# how to change title with data in database laravel backpack

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, laravel-backpack

im new at laravel backpack.
Here i want to change the title in layout with my data in database

this is the image

[image]

i want change that 'Backpack' with name in database like:

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('users_id','=', '1')->get('users_name');
```

can i know how to change it with 
the 'users_name' from database? Until know i dont know how to change it.
Thanks before

Answer (score 3):

It's in the `project_name/resources/views/vendor/backpack/base/layout.blad.php`

```
<header class="main-header">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="{{ url('') }}" class="logo"> <!-- Here's what r u looking for -->
          <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
          <span class="logo-mini">{!! config('backpack.base.logo_mini') !!}</span>
          <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
          <span class="logo-lg">{!! config('backpack.base.logo_lg') !!}</span>
        </a>
        <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
          <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
            <span class="sr-only">{{ trans('backpack::base.toggle_navigation') }}</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>

          @include('backpack::inc.menu')
        </nav>
      </header>
```

**1st Way**  (recommended)

`{!! config('backpack.base.logo_mini') !!}` to

```
{{ DB::table('users')->where('users_id','=', '1')->get('users_name') }}
```

Or whatever.
**2nd Way**

In the `project_name/config/backpack/base.php`

```
// Menu logos
'logo_lg'   => '<b>Back</b>pack',
'logo_mini' => '<b>B</b>p',
```

Edit `'<b>Back</b>pack'` for your custom large size logo and edit `'<b>B</b>p'` for your custom mini size logo .

**UPDATE**

If you want to show the authenticated user name,

```
{{ Auth::user()->user_name }}
```